# APNs Testing before app submission

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to test distribution push notification before the first version of app is submitted? I know use adhoc provisioning will work, but I also heard that it is impossible to test before the first version of the app. Anyone know the answer? Currently our app's apns is woking in development  environment, but not working in distribution environment. Thanks.

---

Edit

Finally it's working. We can test distribution push notification before the first version is submitted. My problem was I mistake to import the wrong certificate with the private key.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKdAX.png

Answer (score 1):

AdHoc provisioning works with the production push notifications environment and it is possible to test before the first version of the app.